# Laravel Menus with childs and permissions via eloquent

Tags: laravel, eloquent, relationship, eloquent-relationship

Hello I am trying to fetch menus and its children along with permissions assigned to a role. How can i achieve this via eloquent relations.
tables are roles, menus, role_menus.
user will only see those menus which he have access to.

here is my code:

Here is My Controller way

```
$menuList = Menu::tree()->with('roleMenus')->where('per_select','=',0);
```

Here is model

```js
class Menu extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;
    protected $table = "menus";
    protected $fillable = ['title', 'url', 'parent_id', 'sort_order'];

    public function parent()
    {
        return $this->hasOne('App\Models\Menu', 'id', 'parent_id')->orderBy('sort_order');
    }

    public function children()
    {

        return $this->hasMany('App\Models\Menu', 'parent_id', 'id')->orderBy('sort_order');
    }

    public static function tree()
    {
        return static::with(implode('.', array_fill(0, 100, 'children')))->where('parent_id', '=', '0')->orderBy('sort_order', 'asc')->get();
    }

    public function roleMenus()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Role::class);
    }


}
```

Answer (score 1):

The way i usually handle roles & permissions is with [Spatie Laravel Permissions](https://github.com/spatie/laravel-permission) package.

What i do is create a menu.blade.php file which has all routes defined in it. But each route is rendered based on user permissions only. You can use the "can" method to achieve this. for eg:

```
@if($user->can('articles'))
  <a href="{{ route('articles) }}">Articles</a>
@endif

@if($user->can('settings'))
  <a href="{{ route('settings) }}">Settings</a>
@endif
```

You can change the $user with Auth::guard($yourGuardName)->user() to get the currently authenticated user.

Comment: Thank you Jibon Bose for your answer, but i am using custom made as it is requirement.
I would really appreciate if you could help me with my code.

Comment: In that case, i guess the best option would be to pass your menu list that you retrieve from db to a custom component that iterates over it and renders your menu. This is if you want to do it that way. Else you can do something that replicates the can method of the above package by yourself and do a similar implementation.

Comment: JIbin, 
As you see my tree() function, I want to make a relation or use custom query to get permissions ...